# How to get Spotify Artist Listeners and Followers by City

Tags: spotify

I am trying to develop an application in which I need to resolve a query to get the number of an artist's followers and listeners by a city location.

Thanks in advance,

NOTE:
I have check that It is possible to resolve this question by filtering by country with the search method spotify.search(q="ABBA", type='artist', market='ES') but not by city.

Comment: Their [API object model](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/) does not provide city data.

Answer (score 2):

"Artist location" was a feature present in the Echonest API.

Unfortunately, this feature was not incorporated by the Spotify API when Spotify incorporated Echonest technologies.

However, you have a workaround which is to process **'The Sounds of Spotify'** playlists, many of which were organized by country regions.

You can find a comprehensive dump in the link below:

[Sounds Of Spotify link with spreadsheets and Excel files](https://www.reddit.com/r/spotify/comments/4r3r1c/massive_dump_of_spotify_created_playlists_14k/)

Then you can filter your requests based on cities/states contained in these playlists. It is not perfect, but it is better than nothing.